# Magento 2 show /Hide my custom payment method - (based on zip code) at checkout not working

Tags: magento2, payment

I am creating a custom payment method module.

It is not working in all cases.

Zip code validation works properly for guest customers and newly registering customers.

For already registered customers sometimes zip code validates and show the payment method at checkout page but sometimes not.

I have cleared the cache an tried,still no way.
Following is the code i used.
Please help.

/Model/zipay.php

```
public function isActive($storeId = null)
    {       

        $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
        $cart = $objectManager->get('\Magento\Checkout\Model\Cart');
        $this->cart = $cart;
        $cartCount = $this->cart->getItemsCount();

        $zip  = "";
        $ziparray = []; 

        # Retrieving ship address

        $shippingAddress = $cart->getQuote()->getShippingAddress();
        $address         = $shippingAddress->getData();     
        $zip             = (string)$address['postcode'];  

        # Retrieving backend configured allowed zip details

        $configzip = $this->_scopeConfig->getValue('payment/zipay/zip', \Magento\Store\Model\ScopeInterface::SCOPE_STORE);
        $config_method_status = $this->_scopeConfig->getValue('payment/zipay/active', \Magento\Store\Model\ScopeInterface::SCOPE_STORE);    

        $ziparray = explode(",",$configzip);

        if ($config_method_status == 1){
            if (in_array($zip, $ziparray,TRUE)) {                                   
                $logger->info("zip enabled matched");                   
                return true;
            }else{              
                $logger->info("zip enabled not matched");
                return false;
            }   
        }else{
            $logger->info(" zip not enabled");
            return false;
        }                           
    }
```